# bitbucket pipelines heroku deploy issue

Tags: heroku, bitbucket-pipelines, heroku-api

I'm having trouble deploying my app to heroku, I'm using the heroku_deploy.sh from documentation and get

```
Deploying Heroku Version 82d8ec66d98120ae24c89b88dc75e4d1c225461e
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'source_blob'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'source_blob'
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'output_stream_url'
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

I'm using a custom docker image, but It has python on it, anything else I should make sure exists?

Comment: Hi guys, I don't remember how I solved this issue..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Meteor deployment to Heroku via Pipelines. The culprit seems to be a **secured** API key to HEROKU. Once I removed a tick and had it in plain text it all started to work well.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the solution? what was the location of the tick that you removed? I am having the same problem

Comment: The error indicates a problem with the user's script handling the data returned from Heroku. Secure and insecure environment variables are made available the same way to Pipelines builds, as normal environment variables, so I don't see how this could be related.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting indicates that the Heroku sources API isn't returning a `source_blob` attribute as part its response, causing the script to fail.

Unfortunately, [the deployment script you're using](https://bitbucket.org/rjst/heroku-deploy/src/master/heroku-deploy.sh) has no error handling around creating a new "Source" object via the [Heroku API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-and-release-using-the-api) (lines 18-20), so the most likely problem is a simple authentication failure (incorrect username/password or incorrectly encoded credentials).

My recommendation is to add some logging to the deploy script, inserting `echo $URL_BLOB` after line 20, and see what is being returned by Heroku. It should help you diagnose the problem.

We also have a more recent recommendation around [deploying to Heroku via a Git remote](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-to-heroku-872013667.html), which might work better than this old hacky script. (If you can reply with where you saw it linked from our site, I'll go and update it.)